# Как убрать постоянный вопрос о сохранении при компиляции уже сохраненного буфера в emacs?

Tags: emacs

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

stud - имя файла. И вот так каждый раз при выполнении команды Feed Buffer

Comment: Каким emacs пользуетесь? В моем `GNU Emacs 25.2.2 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.21)` такой команды вообще нет